# Distance between $e^x$ and $\ln x$ using tangent/normal method

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions, calculus-of-variations

I have been trying to find the shortest distance between $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\ln(x)$.

All methods I have seen include taking the $y=x$ line as the mirror and find a point on both curves which have same slope as the mirror ($1$ in this case).

Now this method is working only because it is a very specific case as the functions are inverse of each other. The general method would be to find a common normal between the two curves and calculate the distance from where the normal intersects them.

I am trying to apply this method for the given question but am getting unexpected results.

First I found derivatives for both curves, took their reciprocals, and multiplied them by a minus sign to get the slope of the normal:

$m_{f(x)normal}=-\frac{1}{e^x}$

$m_{g(x)normal}=-x$

Now, both these slopes must be equal in case of a common normal.

But equating them yields:

$xe^x=1$

This is far from the actual answer of $x=1$ and $x=0$ where the normal intersect the curves.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for the distance between the graphs (as sets of points) or for $\min (e^x-\ln x)$?

Comment: @AI.G. I am trying to find the minimum distance between them

Comment: There a lots of different meanings for the "difference of two functions." Please update the question with your intended meaning

Comment: I think your method is almost correct, but the problem is that this method assumes the normal intersects both curves at exactly the same value of $x$, which  is not necessarily true, as the shared normal of two curves can intersect one curve at one value of $x$, but the other curve - at another. If we instead try to solve, say, $e^{x_1}x_2=1$, then the actual answers fit in quite well (e.g. $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$). Knowing the $x$-values and corresponding $y$-values you can then find the distance using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @himanshu the normal slope may be the same, but the parameter that goes in, for eg, $(t,e^t)$, and $(u,ln(u)$ are not the same, which you seem to be assuming. In essence what you are calculating is the point $"x"$ where the slope of the normal of curve 1 is equal to slope of normal of curve 2. What you should be doing is, writing the normal slope formula at a parameter $t$ for curve 1, and at a parameter $u$ for curve 2, and finding a relation between the parameters.

Comment: I somehow completely overlooked that $x$ in both slopes will be different. Thanks for pointing it out Tom and nickbros123

Comment: @Himanshu Also, if you will use this method, you might need to add more conditions, as even when the slopes of normals to the curves are the same, we might not be able to draw a shared normal through such points on both curves. Slopes can be the same, but $y$-intercepts of normals can be different, which will cause issues.

Comment: @Tom that's a good point but I am pretty sure at least one common normal can always be drawn between two curves provided they do not intersect each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slopes you have computed for the normal for each curve are correct, but it is not always necessary that they are equal for the same value of $x$.

It must be the case that for some $x_1$, the slope of the normal at a point $(x_1, e^{x_1})$ on the curve $y=e^x$ is $-\frac{1}{e^{x_1}}$, which is equal to $(-x_2)$ which is the slope of the normal at another point $(x_2,\ln(x_2))$ on the curve $y= \ln x $.

Proceeding from this premise, we write the equations for the normal for $y=e^x$ and $y=\ln x$:

$$y-e^{x_1} = -\frac{1}{e^{x_1}}\cdot (x-x_1)$$

$$ y - \ln(x_2) = -x_2 \cdot (x-x_2)$$

Now, since these two equations represent the same normal, we equate the coefficients of $y$, $x$ and the constants. We obtain:

$$ 1 = 1$$

$$-\frac{1}{e^{x_1}} = -x_2    \tag1$$

and

$$ \frac{x_1}{e^{x_1}} + e^{x_1} = x_2^2 + \ln(x_2)      \tag2$$

Using equation $(1)$, we rewrite rquation $(2)$ as:

$$ x_1 x_2 + \frac{1}{x_2} = x_2^2 + \ln(x_2)$$

From this, you can see that the values $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$ satisfy the equations.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I somehow completely overlooked that $x$ in both the equations would be different.